# How to load an epsg 4326 wmts layer in google map js api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google map javascript api v3.. is there a way / example to load epsg 4326 wmts layer in Google map?

Comment: There is a great a example here https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/caching_data/using_gwc.html